# chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage not working on Opera 16

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I have an extension for Chrome that was working fine on Opera 15 (and works fine on Chrome 29).

Stating with Chrome 16, I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getBackgroundPage' of undefined

Spefically, chrome.extension is undefined.

The code in question is:

function _getBackgroundPage()
{
  return chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
}

Did something change or break in Opera 16?

The add-on is here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webde-mailcheck/jaogepninmlbinccpbiakcgiolijlllo?hl=en

And the error occurs when going to Options and clicking "Add..." to add a new account.

At the core, the problems seems to be loading a chrome URL into an iframe (on another chrome page). This is allowed in Opera 15 but it broke in Opera 16.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, thats a bug in Opera. We're aware of it and are working to fix it.

Cheers,

Comment: And you waited just long enough to respond that I got the Tumbleweed badge for this question :). I thought I was forgotten.